# How can I find out which branches a TFS changeset has been merged into

Tags: tfs

If I have a TFS changeset ID, can I find out which other branches that changeset has been merged into? (using VS2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with 2008 since we're only using 2010 here.

To do this in 2010, you can find the changeset in the branch it was created in (history view etc), right click and select Track Changeset, you can then select all the branches you want to see such as dev, prod, release etc. This should then show where the changeset was merged from and to (personally I find it easier to go to the Timeline Tracking to visualise it better).

Shows the original changeset, and any changeset that it has been merged as part of.

Hope this helps, sorry I can't check against 2008!

Comment: It's not supported in TFS2008 but I'll mark this as the answer as it is definitely the solution going forwards.